# how CEPH Object store files

Tags: object, storage, ceph

I am not a developer so this is not a technical question. We're looking at using CEPH storage by adding it to our current application but I can't seem to get an answer for how CEPH store files if we plan to use CEPH Object Storage.  If I send a 1GB file to CEPH Object store, does CEPH split the file in "Chunks" and store it across multiple OSD? OR does CEPT storage that single 1GB file on multiple OSD?

Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ceph stripes data (similar to RAID 0). You can refer to [HOW CEPH CLIENTS STRIPE DATA](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/cuttlefish/architecture/#how-ceph-clients-stripe-data) for the detail.

Comment: Please extract the relevant parts of the post and post here along with your answer.